# Pattern Matching on a List in Elm

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, elm

Can you pattern match on a list of items in Elm 0.18?  For example:

```
type Thing = Foo | Bar | Baz

things : List Thing
things : [ Foo, Bar, Baz ]

caseStatement : Thing -> Bool
caseStatement thing =
  case thing of
    expressionSayingThatItIsInThingsList ->
      True
    _ ->
      False
```

Also, can this be done in Haskell?

Comment: In Haskell you would need to first create an instance of `Eq` for `Thing`, and then use the `elem` function.

Comment: Your caseStatement reminds me of GHC's [View Patterns](http://neilmitchell.blogspot.be/2009/11/reviewing-view-patterns.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elm is based on Haskell, actually has lot of less features, you can pattern match your type easily element by element or check if it is in the list:

```
data Thing = Foo | Bar | Baz deriving (Eq, Show)

things :: [Thing]
things = [ Foo, Bar, Baz ]

caseStatement :: Thing -> Bool
caseStatement thing = thing `elem` things
```

Pattern matching:

```
caseStatement :: Thing -> Bool
caseStatement Foo = True
caseStatement Bar = True
caseStatement Baz = True
caseStatement _   = False
```

Here you have a [live example](https://repl.it/Kopy/1)

In Elm you can use `List.member`

```
import List
type Thing = Foo | Bar | Baz

things : List Thing
things = [ Foo, Bar, Baz ]

caseStatement : Thing -> Bool
caseStatement thing = List.member thing things
```

Pattern matching it:

```
caseStatement : Thing -> Bool
caseStatement thing = case thing of
    Foo -> True
    Bar -> True
    Baz -> True
    _   -> False
```

Comment: I ended up going with `List.member thing things`.  However, is there any way to drop something like that into a case statement?  For example: `Foo|Bar|Baz ->`, or some kind of regex.  If case expressions are definitely only designed for simple, direct matches, put that at the top of the response and I'll mark as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes!

```
case thing of
   Foo :: Foo :: Bar :: [] ->
      "two foos and a bar"
   Bar :: stuff ->
      "a bar and then " ++ (toString stuff)
    _ ->
      "something else"
```

Comment: In Mark's example Thing is a type not a List. Your solution is wrong. This code will not compile.

You will get this:

-- TYPE MISMATCH ---------------------------------------------------------------

Tag :: is causing problems in this pattern match.

Foo :: Foo :: Bar :: [] ->
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
The pattern matches things of type:

    List a

But the values it will actually be trying to match are:

    Thing

Comment: If you make sure thing is a list then it's fine. Of course if thing isn't a list you can't treat it as one. If it's a list, you pattern match on a list as the op requested.